# Kaggle Python course Exercise: Strings and Dictionaries Q. no. 2

Tags: python, kaggle

Here's the question,
A researcher has gathered thousands of news articles. But she wants to focus her attention on articles including a specific word. Complete the function below to help her filter her list of articles.

Your function should meet the following criteria:

Do not include documents where the keyword string shows up only as a part of a larger word. For example, if she were looking for the keyword “closed”, you would not include the string “enclosed.”

She does not want you to distinguish upper case from lower case letters. So the phrase “Closed the case.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”

Do not let periods or commas affect what is matched. “It is closed.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”. But you can assume there are no other types of punctuation.

Here's my ans(I want to solve this just using loops and ifs):

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.

Example:
  

  doc_list = ['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?']
word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    #non-course provided and my own code starts here.
    
    k=0
    print(doc_list,keyword)
    for string in doc_list:
        print(string)
        for char in string:
            if char.upper()==keyword[0] or char.lower()==keyword[0]:
                print(char,string[string.index(char)-1])
                if (string[string.index(char)-1]==" " or string[string.index(char)-1]=="" or string[string.index(char)-1]==".") and (string[string.index(char)+len(keyword)]==" " or string[string.index(char)+len(keyword)]=="" or string[string.index(char)+len(keyword)]=="."):
                    print(string[string.index(char)-1])
                    for k in range(len(keyword)):
                        print(k)
                        if string[string.index(char)+k].upper()==keyword[k] or string[string.index(char)+k].lower()==keyword[k]:
                            c=c+k
                            if len(c)==len(keyword):
                                x=[doc_list.index(string)]
                            return x
```

But after running the check code:

```
q2.check() #returns,

Incorrect: Got a return value of None given doc_list=['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], keyword='casino', but expected a value of type list. (Did you forget a return statement?)
```

Here's what gets printed out after executing the code:

```
['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 
'Casinoville?'] casino
The Learn Python Challenge Casino
C  
C  
They bought a car, and a horse
c  
Casinoville?
C ?
```

The code is compiling successfully without syntax and other explicit errors. But I can't find any implicit bugs that's generating a wrong ans after struggling for 5+ hrs. please help!

Comment: @Nikaido Hey, got any clue?

Comment: This would be an excellent use case for regular expressions. Are you allowed to use them?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to solve this would be to use the method `contains()`. An example of its usage can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-contains/).
So the algorithm would become:

```
list_to_return = []
counter = 0
for item in doc_list:
  if item.contains(word):
    list_to_return.append(counter)
  counter += 1
return list_to_return
```

Comment: Assalamu Alaykum, I understand that there are better methods but I still want to use this as a part of my learning.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly Kaggle courses also provide you with the solution which is the solution you should understand and use moving forward. Your code has many conditions and it will be tough to determine which of these conditions is not implemented correctly. Might as well check Kaggles' solution because you cant use this moving forward. Also the solution you have has a nested for-loop checking each letter one-by-one. That is extremely inefficient. Nice beginners attempt though :)

Comment: Assalamu Alaykum, I understand that there are better methods but I still want to use this as a part of my learning.

Comment: Fair enough. I see you have used several prints in the code. Can you tell me what gets printed out when you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the answer, your function should return a list. You are instead returning a `None` value, because at some points in your nested ifs you are going at the end of your function, in which is not specified any `return`. When you don't specify any `return` keyword at the end of your function, it will return `None` as default

By the way, python offers a lot of utils libraries, for example the `str.index()` method that return the string index if found in the original string

This I think is a better development of your solution:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword.
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents
    containing the keyword.

    Example:


    doc_list = ['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?']
    word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """

    my_list = []
    for doc in doc_list:
        curr_doc = doc.lower()
        try:
            curr_index = curr_doc.index(keyword.lower())
            my_list.append(curr_index)
        except:
            my_list.append(None)
    return my_list

print(word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], 'casino'))
```

output: `[27, None, 0]`

As you can see, in my code I am returning a List at the end of the function definition, as requested from the problem

Comment: Can you please tell me where my code went incorrect? Using my line of thought.(Loop inside a loop inside a loop...)

Comment: @BelalNoor because at some point, some if is not true. When your if is not true your code goes at the end of your function, and at the end of your function there is no return statement. Anyway you should not return an index, but a list of indexes

Comment: @BelalNoor try for example to make some print inside of your ifs, you'll see that some are never printed, because the if statement is not true. And when that if statement is not true, you code goes at the end of your function, which will return None as default

Comment: Hey, if an if statement is False it goes to the end of the function of the for loop it's inside?

Comment: Probably they are always false in the for loop

Comment: @BelalNoor for example, try to put a print in the last if statement. You'll see that it will never printed. Anyway you shouldn't return in that point. In that way if you find the keyword in a sentence you'll return without searching for the others in the other sentences

Comment: Hey, do you mean that an if statement is always False in case of a loop in the sentence "Probably they are always false in the for loop"?

Comment: @BelalNoor yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using regex

```py
import re
def word_search(documents, keyword):
    res=[]
    for i,j in enumerate(documents):
        if re.findall('\\b'+keyword+'\\b',j,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            res.append(i)
    return res
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    res = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(doc_list)-1):
        if(doc_list[i] == keyword):
            sum=sum+1
            res.append(doc_list[i])
    return sum, res
```

Comment: Hi, your answer needs more explanation check this link to find how to write a good answer at Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer